# datasnapshot doesn't get value from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I guess the problem must be there but I couldn't figure it out. I want to reach the title but I can't always snapshot returns null also no problem about connection because when I check user id I can reach that.

```
  DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference titleRef = rootRef.child("users").child("value").child("title");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {
            titleRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
                    String title = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", title);
                    System.out.println(title);
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

[image]

----my data structure----

```js
{
  "users" : {
    "value" : {
      "title" : "dsfdfasd"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. Did you run the code in a debugger already? If so, and you put a breakpoint on the first line inside `onDataChange`, does it reach that line? If it does, and you log `snapshot.getValue()`, what does it output?

Comment: i use to android emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database schema looks like this:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "value" : {
      "title" : "dsfdfasd"
    }
  }
}
```

To be able to get the value of "title", please use the following reference

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference titleRef = rootRef.child("users").child("value").child("title");
```

Call get() and attach a listener like this:

```
titleRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            String title = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", title);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
dsfdfasd
```

Besides that, always log the error instead of blindly assuming that everything works fine.

Comment: when i tried this i get "Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 17444
    java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message" this error on the   "Log.d("TAG", title);" here

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry, my bad. A call to `.child("users")` was missing. Please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: unfortunately no. Still same problem.

Comment: No, it should work. Please edit your question and show us the changed code and also add a screenshot of your database.

Comment: What is the location of your database?

Comment: i couldn't exactly what is location but if you ask me about firebase project settings  thats all true i checked  a few times  also i can get useruid in my database well i work on firebase

Comment: Is your database location the (default) "us-central1"? The user ID isn't related to the location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236673/discussion-between-samsa-and-alex-mamo).

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is not compatible with your code

```
ref.child(userID)....
```

There is no uid in your data structure. Instead you have value.